# Having two INSTALL_REFERRER receivers on the manifest... will work the two?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcastreceiver

What happens if you have two receivers declared on the manifest with the same intent type?

For example:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.myReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.myReceiver2"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Both will be called? Or only one? Can't find anything about this in the official documentation

Comment: Both of them should be called, if not one of them cancels the broadcast. But have you tried it?

Comment: not me, did you? someone has told me this will not work. I haven't the test environment to check it atm

Comment: Both will be called. A simple Google search would've answered your question.

Comment: @PrajjwalSrivastav  do you have that link please?